# NDVI and variations

Tags: qgis, ndvi, landsat

I'm trying to create a variation on an NDVI. However, the Landsat Imagery I have keeps doing this
[image]

or this

[image]

Even though the original bands load fine (here's an example)

[image]

Anyone have an ideas?!

Comment: Welcome to GIS.SE! Please take the [tour] to better understand how this site works. Also, the screenshots alone don't make it clear what is *this* that the LS images keep doing. Please edit and update your question with a more detailed description along the standard problem-reporting lines: 1) What did you do? 2) What did you expect to happen? 3) What did actually happen?